# How did the Red Woman know that Gendry has royal blood?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In season 3 of *Game of Thrones*, Melisandre the "Red Woman" exchanges Gendry by paying lots of gold to the Brotherhood Without Banners. Later, she reveals that Gendry has royal blood as he is Robert's son. Very few people were aware of this fact and he was one of very less known bastards. Even he himself was not aware. So how did she know that?

Comment: she can smell it

Comment: In the books it was a different character who was well-known to be Robert's bastard and boasted about it, and I don't think anything in the show addresses this directly, so I think the answer is *probably* a disappointing "We don't know, maybe she saw him in the flames or something". At a stretch, in the books it's mentioned that Jon Arryn was in close communication with Stannis about his investigations, so *maybe* you could say Jon told Stannis that Gendry was a dark-haired Baratheon bastard, and Stannis told Mel? But I think in the show, Stannis was 100% surprised about Robert's kids...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**She was sent there by the Lord of Light of himself.**

In S3E6, when Melisandre meets with Thoros and Beric they have an exchange (at about 5:44 in the [linked video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEj1aN_Rmj0))

> Beric: He sent you to us for a reason.
>
> Melisandre: You have someone he needs.

We do need to do a little extrapolation/assumption, but as seen in other places, Melisandre communicated with R'hollor through the flames. I see no reason why this would any different.